# flex: call parent method from module using Interface

Tags: apache-flex, module

I am using [this guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64277-7fea.html) for passing data to modules "Using interfaces for module communication". For getting child module instances they have done this

```
var ichild:* = mod.child as IModuleInterface; (mod = moduleLoader)
```

What should I do to get instance of parent application inside module?
How can I call parent methods inside modules?

Comment: Aside note: why * when type should be IModuleInterface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. Just pass any class instance in your main application to module, which methods you want to call.

Your module:

```
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:Script><![CDATA[

        public var appInst : Object;

        public function CallAlert() : void
        {
            if (appInst != null)
                appInst.AppAlert("Hello from module");
        }

        ]]></mx:Script>
    <mx:Button click="CallAlert()" label="click"/>
</mx:Module>
```

Your main application:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        public function AppAlert(str : String) : void
        {
            Alert.show(str);
        }

        public function ready(evt : Event) : void
        {
            mod.child["appInst"] = this;
        }

        ]]></mx:Script>
    <mx:ModuleLoader
            id="mod"
            width="100%"
            url="module.swf"
            ready="ready(event)"/>
</mx:Application>
```

The [ ] operator is an alternative way to use properties and methods of objects. We can't use here `mod.child.appInst` here, because `mod.child` is DisplayObject, and it has no such property. But our module main class has property `appInst`. It's an alternative way to using interface.
You may pass any variables or functions to your module application. So that's it.

P.S. Be careful with errors of type casting and unexisting properties.